# Is really any token metadata stored on chain? Or is it the mint TX metadata?

Tags: nft, metadata, on-chain

I am aware that offchain metadata is stored using the registration as Cardano Developers portal dictates, my concern is about on-chain metadata.

Is really any NFT-metadata stored on-chain? Like blockfrost says?   Since  NFT are just pairs of police id and name... Where is onchain metadata stored ?  As far as i understand metadata can only be attached to a TX ... So the metadata should be attached to the mint- TX Wich can be always traced and is stored in blockchain,  is this right ?

Or i am getting confused at comparing two different kind of native assets ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is NFT metadata stored on-chain and yes they are stored initially on the mint tx although you can update it later (basically overriding it in a new tx). If the NFT metadata follow the [CIP25](https://cips.cardano.org/cips/cip25/) you'll see it "properly" rendered on several sites such as [pool.pm](https://pool.pm/ccb3577601d6cf0e021288871112926338bee685c6c37eeadf6dddd9.CardaniaFounderRed).

Comment: So it is TX metadata, not NFT - metadata, but they associate this metadata to the NFT by tracking all the history of the asset to the initial mint , and it's updated in every mint .. if policy allow minting that same asset.. right ?

Comment: @AliciaBasilio, strictly speaking it's TX metadata, just remember an NFT is meant to be unique so it should not allow more minting, but of course it all depends on the policy specifications